# my mouse pointer in my laptop is not moving

Tags: mouse

I have asusX555LN laptop. My problem is when I turn
on my laptop,after some time My laptop's mouse pointer
get stuck. I can not move my mouse pointer through
mousepad.. what should I do? I have windows 10 OS.

Answer (score 0):

Connect an external mouse (possibly through USB).
If the problem persist, try to disable the built-in touchpad, either in the Device Manager, on in PC BIOS.
If the problem disappears, then it is connected with the touchpad.

After that, it may be either a hardware or software problem. But first try to resolve the previous.